# how to change default automount umask on 13.04?

Tags: automount

when I plug in my usb hdd, ubuntu 13.04 will mount it to /media/myname/label, but the umask is 700, I try to change it by "chmod 755 xxxxx", but no effect.

So, how to change default umask?

BTW: my usb hdd is stored some movies, I want to use plex media server to scan them, but pms cannot find anything from hdd path, so I think it is a umask issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1502775) answer from UbuntuForums is sort of right:

> You'll need to create an fstab entry that uses auto mount, I haven't
>   done this in a long time but you could try adding the following to
>   /etc/fstab:
>
> /dev/sdx /path/to/mnt ntfs-3g
>   auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0
>
> Then umount and try plugging it back in to see if that works. If you
>   just want the same permissions for file/directory you could replace
>   f/dmask with umask.

The sort of wrong part is that it uses disk indices instead of UUIDs or disklabels.  The point does, however, remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do the same entry with disk UUID.

Simply change the above thing into

**UUID=""** /path/to/mnt ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0

sudo blkid will show you the UUID of the desired disk.
PS- pay attention to the double quotes.