# How to change umask mode permanently?

Tags: permissions, umask

I've read a couple of articles like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328400/how-to-change-default-automount-umask-on-13-04) old one how to change *umask* mode but still can't figure it out 100% I have Ubuntu 14.04 running with Xenial kernel with default *umask 0002* and my aim is to set *0027 umask* mode permanently all across the system. How do I make it happen? What be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @waltinator for pointing me for the right direction.

From here I figured easy step how to set *umask* mode to *0027* just run in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/login.defs
```

or with `nano` which one you prefer.

search for the line:

```
Prefix these values with "0" to get octal, "0x" to get hexadecimal.

ERASECHAR   0177
KILLCHAR    025
UMASK       027
```

Edit the last line refering *UMASK* this will set *umask* to *0007* to take effect simply log out and log in back.

Make a notice on the lines above: *If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK default value...used as group permissions, e. g. 022 will become 002*

So for the *umask 0027* to take effect roll down to the line:

```
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes
```

and change it to:

```
USERGROUPS_ENAB no
```

Done. After you logged out and log in back run in terminal `umask` and it'll give you `0027` mode.

Now create a new file with `touch` in terminal:

```
touch testfile
```

now check the permissions:

```
stat -c %a ~/testfile
```

It should give you *640*

**UPDATE**

There's another simple way:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

add

```
#Set umask mode
umask 0027
```

Close and save, logout and login. Should work for you as well.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me until later there was another bug with dbus in Ubuntu after 17.04. Please read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1685754/comments/21

Comment: The ~/.bashrc variant does not work for me (Ubuntu 20.04.1).

Comment: The login.defs variant does not work for me neither (login via ssh).

Comment: With the simple method you have to run bash at least once to change umask, otherwise new files created via GUI will have different default permissions than you expect.
The `USERGROUPS_ENAB` variable set to `yes` is convenient because thanks to it, when executing the `deluser` command, the group with the same gid as the user uid and the same name as the user is also deleted (if the group has no other members), without having to do it later.

Comment: The only way without side effects is if you want to change the `umask` to `0022` and it is done by unsetting `UMASK` in `/etc/login.defs` because this value stops being affected by the value of `USERGROUPS_ENAB` variable. e.g. `UMASK  022` becomes `#UMASK  022`.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo Are you saying that if you want to change the umask to 0022 the only thing you need to do is comment out the `#UMASK 022` line and nothing else?

Comment: @KevinWheeler Exactly. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

A simple `man -k umask` should have led you to reading `man pam_umask`, whish says, in part:

```
DESCRIPTION
pam_umask is a PAM module to set the file mode creation mask of the
current environment. The umask affects the default permissions assigned
to newly created files.
```

It also says,

```
The PAM module tries to get the umask value from the following places
   in the following order:

   ·   umask= argument

   ·   umask= entry in the user's GECOS field

   ·   UMASK= entry from /etc/default/login

   ·   UMASK entry from /etc/login.defs (influenced by USERGROUPS_ENAB in
       /etc/login.defs)
```

Comment: in /etc/login.defs I found two lines like: Login configuration initializations *UMASK  Default "umask" value.* and further *UMASK  022* what should I change over here? looks like I've tried to put myself 022 but still when I run in terminal *umask* it says 0002

Comment: here's one thing I got now after I change that *022* value to *027* and when I run *umask* in terminal now I get *umask 0007* so how do I get *0027*? I tried to put *047* but it's still gets me *0007*

Answer (score 4):

I was using JoKeR's answer above to achieve a system wide umask of 027 but I was conscious that when I used `USERGROUPS_ENAB no` it required more group management. So I feel I have found a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531/how-to-set-system-wide-umask), basically:

1. Make sure that the pam-modules package is installed; that makes the pam_umask module available.
2. Make sure that /etc/pam.d/common-session has a line of the form

   ```
   session optional pam_umask.so
   ```

   so that pam_umask is enabled.
3. According to the pam_umask man page, the default umask is determined at login by checking each of the following places, in order:

   - A hard system-wide default set in /etc/pam.d/common-session. To set
        it this way, replace the line from that file mentioned above with
        this:

     ```
     session optional pam_umask.so umask=027
     ```
   - An entry in an individual user's GECOS field in /etc/passwd overrides a soft system-wide default for that specific user. Create that entry using a command of the form:

     ```
     chfn --other='umask=027' username
     ```
   - A line of the form `UMASK=027` in /etc/default/login (you may need to create that file) sets a soft system-wide default.
   - The UMASK value from /etc/login.defs. That value is also used for
        something else (computing the permissions on the home directory of a
        new user that is being created; see the comments in /etc/login.defs
        for more details). So it is best to avoid relying on this for setting
        the default umask for regular logins, to keep things separate.

So now for me I use the first option (system-wide default set in /etc/pam.d/common-session) and it's working really well.

Good luck my friends :)