# Why is UMASK set in /etc/login.defs ignored?

Tags: unity, umask

I have set `UMASK 077` in `/etc/login.defs` and there is no override in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

The `umask` command still prints `0022` in gnome-terminal, but prints `0007` when I log into `tty1`. Newly created files get the same permissions as when `umask` is set to `0022`.

Ubuntu version: 16.10

Comment: Logout and login. The `umask` value is session specific. If you want the value instantly, just do `umask 0077`

Comment: Tried even a system reboot!

Comment: Did you see http://askubuntu.com/a/276958/158442?

Comment: Try this [article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/805862/how-to-change-umask-mode-permanently) here it should help resolve the issue.

Comment: @Chandru, It seems that the GUI/X session, override it somehow, so it does not follow the global setting in `/etc/login.defs` (it could be hard-coded, because there are some similar questions in unix and so, w/out accepted answer too)

Comment: @Chandru, I could find a note in https://wiki.debian.org/DebianDesktopHowTo#System *`Note that the GNOME display manager (gdm) overrides the system's default umask. Thus, if you use gdm you may try to fix it, or just install another dm like kdm, slim, or LightDM. `* but I think most DM's do same as GDM.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the `/etc/login.defs` and change these values accordingly:

1. UMASK 077 - *as you earlier did*
2. Change this `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes` to `USERGROUPS_ENAB no`

Now log out then log back in. Create a new file and check the default permissions. Hope it helps.

Comment: But I want `USERGROUPS_ENAB` to remain enabled. My problem is not with `umask` being `0007` in tty1. That is the desired behaviour.

The problem is `umask` remaining `0022` in Unity and gnome-terminal, even after setting `UMASK` in `login.defs`.

Comment: @Chandru, set the `TTYPERM to 0770` then set `USERGROUP_ENAB to yes` log out log in and test. Please still leave the `UMASK` at `077`

Comment: I don't think `TTYPERM` has anything to do with `umask`!

Comment: @Chandru, this might help `man pam_umask` read and see if it is what you require.

Comment: Didn't make any difference.